# Why is this environment variable always null?

Tags: c#, winforms, environment-variables

I want to automatically get the directory: `user\mydocuments`
So I did:

```
t = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal));
```

But `t` is null all the time.

Comment: What did you think that would do? What did you think that `GetEnvironmentVariable` would do? Do you know what an environment variable is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source of the problem is that you are calling `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` when you really don't need to.

Your code successfully obtains the directory path but then you proceeded pass said directory path to `GetEnvironmentVariable()` which in turn, proceeds to look at the system's environment variables for an environment variable called "user\my_documents". Because no such environment variable exists the function will return `null`.

Simply do not pass the directory path to `GetEnvironmentVariable()` and your code should function as expected:

```
var foo = 
     Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```